# wsHttpBinding app config for ServiceContract sessions

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, session, config

Hallo i want to user  `SessionMode = SessionMode.Required` and i read that wcf service must has `wsHttpBinding` because supports sessions. Now i make one `app.config` for configuration and i make one function in windows form to start the servives. When i click a button and call `StartWCFServer()` i get this exception:

`InvalidOperationException was unhandled`

`Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].`

Here is my codes:

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="WCF_Server.WCFService">
        <endpoint  address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindings" contract="WCF_Server.IWCFService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug httpsHelpPageEnabled="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">

        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBindings">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

**StartWCFServer()**

```
     ServiceHost host;
     private void StartWCFServer()
            {
                if (host == null)
                {
                    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/");
                    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService), baseAddress);
                    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWCFService), new WSHttpBinding("wsHttpBinding"), "Services");
                        host.Open();//<-- Exception here
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are setting it as `<add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>` but in host you are using `Uri baseAddress = new Uri(http+ your site's URL);`

so change `scheme="https"` to `scheme="http"`

Comment: I get same exception.

Comment: try to add base-address section to your config file and see whether it's working or not.

Comment: i change address="" to address="myhost" and now i get exception: Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'WSHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.